# Determinar si una extensión de Chrome fue instalada desde el web store

Tags: javascript, extensión-google-chrome

Estoy desarrollando una extensión de Chrome: pruebo localmente, armo el zip, subo al store, y vuelvo a empezar. Algunas funciones son de depuración, y deberían activarse solamente cuando la estoy probando localmente.

¿Hay alguna forma de determinar si la extensión fue instalada desde el web store o si la cargué como extensión descomprimida en modo desarrollador?

---

* Pensé que podía estar en [`chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getPackageDirectoryEntry), pero no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar el método [`chrome.management.getSelf`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#method-getSelf) que: (traducción mía)

> Devuelve información sobre la extensión, app o theme que la llama. Nota: Esta función puede ser usada sin solicitar los permisos de 'management' en el manifest.

Y que devuelve un objeto de tipo [`ExtensionInfo`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#type-ExtensionInfo) que contiene la propiedad 
`installType` (del tipo [`ExtensionInstallType`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#type-ExtensionInstallType)). Entonces sólo tendrías que comprobar el valor de esa propiedad para determinar cómo se instaló la extensión.

`installType` es un enum que puede tener alguno de estos valores:

- `admin`: la extensión se instaló por una política administrativa.
- `development`: la extensión se cargó desde el modo de desarrollador.
- `normal`: la extensión fue instalada de manera normal con una fichero .crx.
- `sideload`: la extensión fue instalada por otro programa en la máquina.
- `other`: la extensió se instaló de otra manera.

Si al comprobar `installType` recibes el valor "development", entonces la cargaste como extensión descomprimida en modo desarrollador; si recibes el valor "normal", entonces  fue instalada desde el web store.

Comment: Perfecto. Era esto. Al principio no me funcionó hasta que lo probé desde el background.

Answer (score 3):

Alvaro [respondió lo que necesitaba](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/81412/27076). El método no *devuelve* el valor, sino que llama a un callback. Así quedó el código funcionando:

```
chrome.management.getSelf(function (extensionInfo) {
    if (extensionInfo.installType == 'development') {

        console.log('Mensaje sólo para cuando estoy depurando (se cargó descomprimida)');
        // ... otras funciones

    }
});
```

---

> **Importante:** La API no funciona desde un [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), y tiene que ser llamada desde el background (o page/browser action).

Comment: +1. Y gracias por la nota, me centré sólo en la teoría y no lo expliqué bien, pero con tu ejemplo se ve más claro.